# I am trying to make an apk with kivy and buildozer but I find an error

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

```
running make -j 8 -C /Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Deskto...(and 129 more)
           working: make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1                                 Exception in thread background thread for pid 1163:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/kivy_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 1637, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/kivy_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2561, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/kivy_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2265, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/kivy_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 865, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/make -j 8 -C /Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build

  STDOUT:
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -I/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include/internal -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I. -I/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN  -DPy_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN -I/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include/internal -c /Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Modules/posixmodule.c -o Modules/posixmodule.o
/Users/lorenzopasquarelli/Desktop/KIVY-INTRODUCTION/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Modules/posixmodule.c:9084:15: error: 
      implicit declaration of function 'sendfile' is invalid in C99
      [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        ret = sendfile(in, out, offset, &sbytes, &sf, flags);
              ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1
```

I found an error creating an apk with buildozer and kivy. I use python at version 3.9.1 but have had problems creating it. If anyone can help me write it, thank you very much

Comment: What OS? As [stated in the docs _Buildozer currently works only in Linux_](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html)